# Submit button css. The outline in Firefox

Tags: css, forms, firefox

I want to control de design of the submit button of a form but I don't want to get rid off the outline (the blue border around) on focus. I have problems with Firefox.

I think it is important for accessibility and because a lot of people use the tab to fill the forms. The outline gives an orientation to see what is selected.

I think the key point is the border, I think that to control the design I should give some css to the border, even border none.  If I give a border in Firefox, the outline disappear and some ugly dotted lines appear. I can get rid of that lines with ::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;} But then, I don't know how to give a shadow only to Firefox.

So there the question is:

- Can I control the design of a submit button in a different way that could work in all browsers, even Firefox?
- How can I give an **outline or shadow that could work in Firefox** ?

I have the example live here: http://jsfiddle.net/56mfx/15/

CSS:

```
input[type="submit"] {    
    width: 80px;
    height: 25px; 
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border:solid thin #ddd;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value"send" id="submit">​
```

Comment: The 'ugly dotted lines' _are_ the outline. They are also an important accessibility feature for keyboard users of your website or application.

Comment: That is the point. This is the reason that I want the original outline (the blue shadow) or a way to design my own outline.

Comment: That's nice. http://outlinenone.com/

Comment: Dotted lines are different to other browsers, (this can be confusing for the user) and they are not clear, it just seems an error. Anyway this is better than nothing. I understand the accessibility reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know, you could just create a `<div>` and then have that submit your form.

```
<div class="sbmtBtn" onmouseup="document.forms['myform'].submit()">Submit</div>
```

And then style it

```
.sbmtBtn{
    width: 80px;
    height: 25px; 
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border:solid thin #ddd;
    /* Use the following to set a shadow only in FF */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000000;
}
```

I always prefer to use a `<div>` as a button because I have more control.

Comment: Using a `div` here is non-semantic and may cause accessibility problems.

Comment: I tested `-moz-box-shadow` in FX 16.0.2 and it does not work.

Comment: I think -moz-box-shadow does not work  : codepen.io/anon/pen/eifwJ Anyway to create a div is an option to have more control. Thank you

Comment: @Nrc No problem my friend. Remember to accept an answer if you got everything you needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the custom submit button for you. You can also use image.

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
```

CSS:

```
.submit{
    background:#BDBDBD;
    height:30px;
    width:100px;
    border:none;
    color:#2E2E2E;
    font:family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.submit:hover{
    background:#DF01D7;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I Perhaps I did not explain well. The question is to have the outline (the blue shadow around when is selected) in all the browsers, especially Firefox. This is for accessibility reasons and because a lot of people fill the forms using the tab.

Comment: You should look here with firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/JrEnp/1/ THe dotted lines appear. We can get rid of that with ::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;} But the question is how to create an outline that I could control

Comment: The :hover is a think to consider. Thank you. But what I was asking is the outline, I mean the selection that is made when using the tab. This is another thing

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve with:

```
input[type="submit"] {    
     width: 80px;
     height: 25px; 
     color: #fff;
     background-color: #ccc;
     border:solid thin #ddd;
     outline: none;

     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #333;

     /* or for outline:
     -moz-outline: 1px solid #c00;
     */
}
```

Comment: I tested here and it does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/56mfx/15/ I don't understand, what is the difference from the initial option in the question?